# How to distribute python software to users of low technical ability?

Tags: python, software-distribution

I have a python application (3.5) that I’m trying to distribute. It:

- Uses no GUI libraries (it runs in the browser)
- Uses several external packages (Flask, SocketIO, httplib2)
- maintains saved config and data files inside the main source directory

The target users:

- Use Mac or Windows
- Do not understand the concept of the terminal/command line (testing has shown that it can take hours to teach users how to `cd` into the source directory to run a `.py` file).
- Generally have little difficulty installing the python interpreter from [python.org](https://python.org) (but have great trouble starting and exiting the python console).
- Are generally of very low technical ability.

Preferably, the app should:

- be “click and play”, as I have found that typically the `cd` navigation is the biggest hurdle preventing users from running my application.
- not require manually modifying any system settings

I am developing from Ubuntu Linux. I have access to a Windows VM, but not a Mac computer. How do I distribute my application?

Comment: You should do some research of your own, however, [`cx_Freeze`](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of applications that can help you to distribute a Python Application, for this case you want to take a look on Python freezing tools like [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) (windows only) or [py2app](https://pythonhosted.org/py2app/) (MacOs).

This two will help you distribute your code without all the hassle of making the user to install the dependencies and run anything from the command line.

However if your application runs on the browser, you probably want to just put that into a server (take a look of openshift, it's free)  it will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: how do i build exes for mac osx if i don’t have a mac computer?